# how to change datepicker size in kivy (through python code)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have adate picker object and because the screen dimantion I set are 310*580(because the app is intended for phones) the datepicker is too big. the code is:

```
 def show_date_picker(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker(primary_color = (0,.811,.407,1), text_toolbar_color = (1,1,1,1))
        date_dialog.open()
```

I've tried using size and size_hint. size didnt work and size_hint difformed it in weird ways (making it bigger istead of smaller, shrinking the text size, and mispositioning the ok and cancel buttons)